# How to add background color for the tabs inside rich:tabPanel

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces

i have added rich:tabPanel and applied style for tabPanel. But unable to add background color for the tabs inside the tabPanel.Can someone tell the styleClass for rich:tab

XTML

```
<td width="80%" height="100%" style="vertical-align: top;"><rich:tabPanel
                                id="tabId" switchType="ajax" >
                                <rich:tab id="section1">
                                    <ui:include src="/pages/design/hrms/Section1.xhtml" />
                                </rich:tab>
                                <rich:tab id="section2" header="#{msg.lbl_section2}">
                                    <ui:include src="/pages/design/hrms/Section2.xhtml" />
                                </rich:tab>
                                <rich:tab id="section3" header="#{msg.lbl_section3}">
                                    <ui:include src="/pages/design/hrms/Section3.xhtml" />
                                </rich:tab>
                                <rich:tab id="section4" header="#{msg.lbl_section4}">
                                    <ui:include src="/pages/design/hrms/Section4.xhtml" />
                                </rich:tab>
                                <rich:tab id="section5" header="#{msg.lbl_section5}">
                                    <ui:include src="/pages/design/hrms/Section5.xhtml" />
                                </rich:tab>
                                <rich:tab id="section6" header="#{msg.lbl_section6}">
                                    <ui:include src="/pages/design/hrms/Section6.xhtml" />
                                </rich:tab>
                                <rich:tab id="section7" header="#{msg.lbl_section7}">
                                    <ui:include src="/pages/design/hrms/Section7.xhtml" />
                                </rich:tab>
                                <rich:tab id="section12" header="#{msg.lbl_section12}">
                                    <ui:include src="/pages/design/hrms/Section12.xhtml" />
                                </rich:tab>
                                <rich:tab id="section13" header="#{msg.lbl_section13}">
                                    <ui:include src="/pages/design/hrms/Section13.xhtml" />
                                </rich:tab>
                                <rich:tab id="section14" header="#{msg.lbl_section14}">
                                    <ui:include src="/pages/design/hrms/Section14.xhtml" />
                                </rich:tab>
                            </rich:tabPanel></td>
```

**style.css**

```
.rf-tab-hdr-spcr {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 2%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 35%, rgba(161, 214, 255, 1) 100% );
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(2%, rgba(255,
        255, 255, 1) ), color-stop(35%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) ),
        color-stop(100%, rgba(161, 214, 255, 1) ) ); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 2%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 35%, rgba(161, 214, 255, 1) 100% );
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 2%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 35%, rgba(161, 214, 255, 1) 100% );
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 2%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 35%, rgba(161, 214, 255, 1) 100% ); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 2%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 35%, rgba(161, 214, 255, 1) 100% ); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(             startColorstr='#ffffff',
        endColorstr='#a1d6ff', GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like it is called `tabId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you verify with Firebug, you will probably notice that your CSS is overriden by the RichFaces style since your CSS isn't as important.

One simple way to change that is to set an id to your `h:form` wrapper and add it to your CSS :

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <!-- code -->

    <rich:tabPanel>
        <!-- code -->
    </rich:tabPanel>

    <!-- code -->
</h:form>
```

And your style.css :

```
#myForm .rf-tab-hdr-spcr {
    /* your css */
}
```

Comment: @user1858826 You want this style on the tabs or on the tabs spacers? For the first one, you need to replace `.rf-tab-hdr-spcr` by `.rf-tab-hdr`, also you should provide `.rf-tab-hdr-act` when the tab is active.

Answer (score -1):

Style classes for `rich:tab` can be found here in [RichFaces3.x guide](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_tab.html) and here for [RichFaces4.x guide](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Panels.html#sect-Component_Reference-Panels-richtabPanel)

As tried out in the below screen shot, you can override the `rich-tab-active` (For style of an active tab) and `rich-tab-inactive` (for style of an inactive tab).

I have overridden `background-color` attribute for active tab with yellow color and `background-color` of an inactive tab with red color. Important thing is remove `background-image` attribute (can be seen in the screen shot).

Try below CSS in your JSP/XHTML page,

```
.rich-tab-active
{
  background-image : none;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

[image: richtab]